# gift-message attribute not appearing in REST API Orders response after setting it on Cart

Tags: orders, rest-api, giftmessage

I am developing a headless Magento backend using REST/Graphql on the frontend.

After enabling the Gift Message module in admin, I set correctly set the Cart gift-message like so:

```
http://localhost/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/gift-message
```

Request body:
`

`{"giftMessage":{"sender": "person a","recipient": "person b","message": "hello to you"}}`

And correctly, receive the response as:

```
true
```

I then place the order and the order is created. Yet, when I GET the full order with REST API, there is no gift-message in the response at all.

The only way to get a gift-message is to manually type it in on Admin Edit Order and hit save, which is unacceptable for various reasons.

Can anyone enlighten me to the flow on this please? Help much appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how to add extension_attributes to your order so you can add a gift message when the order is successfully paid.